# How should I test a method that calls a constructor that calls static/final methods? (Mockito)

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have a method that creates an object, which the constructor of that object then calls several static/final methods. Mockito cannot mock a constructor, and it can also not mock static/final methods, so what am I supposed to do?

--Edit--

Apparently people think my question is unclear: I have a method. It calls a constructor. Constructor is not mockable. How do I test this method?

The reason why I mentioned static/final methods is because I decided I may as well test the constructor as well and mock the methods within that constructor. However, it is full of static/final methods which makes this impossible.

Comment: Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: What have you tried so far, with a code example? ([I downvoted because there is no code](//idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/)) / What do you expect? / What error do you get? For help, take a look at "[How to ask](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)".

Comment: @chriptus13 the question is already very clear without needing an example

Comment: @Goldname: Nope, it isn’t.

Comment: @Nikolas So what exactly is unclear about needing code coverage on a method calling a constructor (which is unmockable)? Is there some advanced topic in Mockito where one can mix up with what I'm talking about?

Comment: @Goldname: Is that hard to provide a minimal sample of the code about to be covered?

Comment: @Goldname, maybe you should not initialize the object inside that method, this way, you can create a mock and pass to the method itself.

Comment: @Nikolas yes, because I don't have mockito/junit installed on my local computer and I'm working off a remote cluster but setting up a new project there just for testing will take a really long time

Comment: @MensurQulami Isn't it bad practice to write additional functions just for the sake of testing it?

Comment: Well, since there is no code example, I am assuming. But no, if the code is not testable there's a big chance that it may not be okay overall. That's not THE rule tho.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mocking static methods with Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21105403/mocking-static-methods-with-mockito)

Answer (score 1):

You can use PowerMockito to mock static methods and also the constructors

For example:
https://automationrhapsody.com/mock-static-methods-junit-powermock-example/

Comment: That's what I've been seeing online, but I cannot use powermockito however

Comment: I don't think that we can do it using mockito without some cheating. You can cheat like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44967108/how-to-mock-static-method-without-powermock