# How to mock just one static method in a class using Mockito?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

The following line seems to mock all static methods in the class:

```
MockedStatic <Sample> sampleMock = Mockito.mockStatic( Sample.class );
sampleMock.when( () -> Sample.sampleStaticMethod( Mockito.any( String.class ) ) ).thenReturn( "response" );
```

Is it possible to mock just one static method in a class?

Edit: the suggested similar question is not similar to this question since the accepted answer there involves using PowerMockito and the answers are for mocking all methods in the class, not just one.

Comment: I updated my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63840969/292728) to include more information that I think will help with this

Comment: @KevinK, I tried your sample and while the method returned what its supposed to return, it was actually called despite being mocked. Is that expected? Did it happen in your sample as well?

Comment: @Kumar it is expected reading the docs. The solution would be to use `doReturn().when()` syntax but is still not supported, check the details on my answer.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

By default all methods are mocked. However, using `Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS` you can configure the mock to actually trigger the real methods excluding only one.

For example given the class `Sample`:

```
class Sample{
    static String method1(String s) {
        return s;
    }
    static String method2(String s) {
        return s;
    }
}
```

If we want to mock only `method1`:

```
@Test
public void singleStaticMethodTest(){
    try (MockedStatic<Sample> mocked = Mockito.mockStatic(Sample.class,Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS)) {
        mocked.when(() -> Sample.method1(anyString())).thenReturn("bar");
        assertEquals("bar", Sample.method1("foo")); // mocked
        assertEquals("foo", Sample.method2("foo")); // not mocked
    }
}
```

---

**Be aware** that the real `Sample.method1()` will still be called. From `Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS` docs:

> This implementation can be helpful when working with legacy code. When
> this implementation is used, unstubbed methods will delegate to the
> real implementation. This is a way to create a partial mock object
> that calls real methods by default.
> ...

> Note 1: Stubbing partial mocks using
> `when(mock.getSomething()).thenReturn(fakeValue)` syntax will call the
> real method. For partial mock it's recommended to use `doReturn`
> syntax.

So if you don't want to trigger the stubbed static method at all, the solution would be to use the syntax `doReturn` (as the doc suggests) but for static methods is still not supported:

```
@Test
public void singleStaticMethodTest() {
    try (MockedStatic<Sample> mocked = Mockito.mockStatic(Sample.class,Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS)) {
        doReturn("bar").when(mocked).method1(anyString()); // Compilation error!
        //...
    }
}
```

About this check this [issue](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/2027).

Comment: did you actually try this method yourself? I tried and it ended up calling the static method that was mocked. Let me try it out in a sample project instead of the legacy project I'm using now.

Comment: Yes I tried myself, using the class `Sample` I provided. It shouldn't be a problem to reproduce it. Let me know otherwise.

Comment: I tried it and the mocked method returns the expected response. But I also noticed that the mocked method is being called (despite the response being what is specified in the test). Is this expected?

Comment: @Kumar It seems to be the expected behavior from the docs (see my updated answer). So the static method is stubbed but still called. The question now is how to use `doReturn` syntax for a static method to ensure that the real stubbed method is not called.

Comment: ...However, using Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS you can configure the mock to actually trigger the real methods... use `@spy` when you want to test actual method with their internal.

Comment: Nice answer. Still working with Mockito 4.6.1

Comment: Especially logged in to thank you :)

Comment: @Kumar I tested now on Feb 2024 for mockito version 5.9.0, and real method is not getting called. 

Code that was run: https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/XhE

Comment: @ManoharBhat interesting. I ran some tests and it seems that the real method is getting called up to Mockito version 3.6. From version 3.7.x is no longer called. Code in [this project](https://github.com/marcello-dev/mock-one-static-method). Funny that the note saying "will call the real method" is [still there](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#CALLS_REAL_METHODS) even in the latest version...